# To create JsonArray

Tags: java, json

I want to create a json structure as following:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": 10021
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        "212 732-1234",
        "646 123-4567"
    ]
}
```

Using add property method I am able to create firstName and lastName but haven't figured out how to create address and phoneNumbers in Java.
Please help me out in this;
Ajay

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need to do is create a new Class called Address which has those properties (string streetAdress, city, state, postalcode). The structure itself will then have an instance of that class.

Also I wouldn't make postalCode an int. Leave it as a string.

PhoneNumbers will be a list of strings (unless you want to do something fancy with it).